# Thread priority not working properly. What wrong i have done in my code?

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have created two classes, `MyThread1` and `MyThread2`, which are extending the Thread class.

```
public class MyThread1 extends Thread{

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread1 output");
    }
}

public class MyThread2 extends Thread{

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread2 output");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyThread1 mt1 = new MyThread1();
        MyThread2 mt2 = new MyThread2();

        mt1.setPriority(10);

        mt1.start();
        mt2.start();
        System.out.println("aaaaaa");
    }
}
```

#

Now according to my program `MyThread1` should run before `MyThread2` because I have set its priority to 10, but still I am getting this output:

Output:

```
Main thread output.                                                      
MyThread2 output.                                                             
MyThread1 output.
```

#

Please someone tell me why `Mythread2` is printed first then `MyThread1` even thought `MyThread1` has high priority.

Comment: Is this `java` ?

Comment: @Cid yes bro. Do you know the answer

Comment: I don't think this would test priority. The tasks are so small, the threads probably don't have any contention. If you run it a bunch, some times 1 is first and sometimes 2 is first.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your problem, I guess you don't save your code before executing. Make sure it's saved and execute again.

When two thread 1 & 2 are created, their priorities inherit from main thread. Let says if main thread has priority is 5, they will be 5.
When you set priority of thread 1 is 10 (max priority). The result should be:

```
Thread 1....
Thread 2 or Main thread ( because of same priority)
```

I have attached my sample code:

```
     Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Runnable 1");
        }
    };
    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Runnable 2");
        }
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    System.out.println("Main thread");
```

Output :

```
Runnable 2
Runnable 1
Main thread
```

Comment: Thanks for replying buddy. But i made a little research and i found out windows10 doesnt provide support to multithreading. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding on the @htpvl,

> In Java, Thread has its own int type variables for the priority values
>   as (`MAX_PRIORITY, NORM_PRIORITY, MIN_PRIORITY`)

you can make use of that as @htpvl explained.

You can also play around its value like increasing or decreasing.
For Example: Lets say you are having 5 thread, and you want to assign the priority accordingly, then what you can do is:

```
// Creating instances
Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
Thread t4 = new Thread(r4);
Thread t5 = new Thread(r5);

// Do check the value of Thread.MAX_PRIORITY, and you can play around it
System.out.println("MAX PRIORITY IS: " + Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); // On Mac it prints : 10
System.out.println("NORMAL PRIORITY IS: " + Thread.NORM_PRIORITY); // On Mac it prints : 5
System.out.println("MIN PRIORITY IS: " + Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); // On Mac it prints : 1

// Set the priority (according to your PRIORITY int values)
t1.setPriority((int)Thread.MAX_PRIORITY-1);
t2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
t3.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
t4.setPriority((int)Thread.NORM_PRIORITY +1);
t5.setPriority((int)Thread.NORM_PRIORITY +2);

// Starting the threads [Execution]
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
t4.start();
t5.start();
```

Output for Thread Sequence:

```
t2
t1
t5
t4
t3
```